# Can not Retrive Single Record Based on Id In Angular JS with Wcf Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wcf

I am trying to retrive single record in Angular JS Application by using wcf Rest Service ..I checked in console windows in google chrome . i got following error ..

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Here is the interfce..

```
     [OperationContract]
            [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
              RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
              ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
              UriTemplate = "/AccountBalanceCheek")]
            AccountBalanceRequest AccountBalanceCheek(AccountBalanceRequest accountNumber);
```

Here is the Implementation.

```
   public AccountBalanceRequest AccountBalanceCheek(AccountBalanceRequest accountNumber)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();

                var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Current_Account_Details WHERE Account_Number = '" + accountNumber.Account_Number + "'", conn);


                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                //read the result of the execute command.
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    //assuming that your property is the same as your table schema. refer to your table schema Current_Account_Details

                    accountNumber.Account_Number= reader["Account_Number"].ToString();
                    accountNumber.Account_Creation_Date = reader["Account_Creation_Date"].ToString();

                    accountNumber.Account_Type = reader["Account_Type"].ToString();
                    accountNumber.Branch_Sort_Code = reader["Branch_Sort_Code"].ToString();
                    accountNumber.Account_Fees = reader["Account_Fees"].ToString();
                    accountNumber.Account_Balance = reader["Account_Balance"].ToString();
                    accountNumber.Over_Draft_Limit = reader["Over_Draft_Limit"].ToString();
                }
                return accountNumber;
            }
        }
```

Here is my Script code ..

```
var app = angular.module("WebClientModule", [])
    .controller('Web_Client_Controller', ["$scope", 'myService', function ($scope, myService) {
    var Id = $scope.Account_Number;
    $scope.search = function (Id) {
        var promiseGetSingle = myService.getbyId(Id);

        promiseGetSingle.then(function (pl) {
            var res = pl.data;
            $scope.Account_Number = res.Account_Number;
            $scope.Account_Creation_Date = res.Account_Creation_Date;
            $scope.Account_Type = res.Account_Type;
            $scope.Branch_Sort_Code = res.Branch_Sort_Code;
            $scope.Account_Fees = res.Account_Fees;
            $scope.Account_Balance = res.Account_Balance;
            $scope.Over_Draft_Limit = res.Over_Draft_Limit;

            //   $scope.IsNewRecord = 0;
        },
            function (errorPl) {
                console.log('failure loading Employee', errorPl);
            });
    }
    }]);




app.service("myService", function ($http) {

    this.getbyId = function (Id) {
        return $http.get("http://localhost:52098/HalifaxIISService.svc/AccountBalanceCheek" + Id);
    };
   })
```

Here is the html.

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app="WebClientModule">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

    <title>AccountBalance</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/RegistrationScript/AccountBalance.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="Web_Client_Controller">
        Enter Account_Number: <input type="text" ng-model="Account_Number" />
        <input type="button"  value="search" ng-click="search(Account_Number)" />

            <table id="tblContainer" data-ng-controller="Web_Client_Controller">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table style="border: solid 2px Green; padding: 5px;">
                            <tr style="height: 30px; background-color: skyblue; color: maroon;">
                                <th></th>
                                <th>Account Number</th>
                                <th>Account Creation Date</th>
                                <th>Account Type</th>
                                <th>Branch Sort Code</th>
                                <th>Account Fees</th>
                                <th>Account Balance</th>
                                <th>Over Draft Limit</th>

                                <th></th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                            <tbody data-ng-repeat="user in Users">
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td><span>{{user.Account_Number}}</span></td>
                                    <td><span>{{user.Account_Creation_Date}}</span></td>
                                    <td><span>{{user.Account_Type}}</span></td>
                                    <td><span>{{user.Branch_Sort_Code}}</span></td>

                                    <td><span>{{user.Account_Fees}}</span></td>
                                    <td><span>{{user.Account_Balance}}</span></td>
                                    <td><span>{{user.Over_Draft_Limit}}</span></td>
                                    <td>

                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>

                        <div style="color: red;">{{Message}}</div>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        </body>


</html>
```

Hers is the appication result in google chrome ..

[image: click here to see the oput put]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you get the 404 not fount error it means something is wrong with your endpoint address. at first try consume your service with fiddler or post man and make sure your service load successfully. then trace your angular request to make sure your client side code works.

Comment: Yes you are right.  When i typed localhost://halifaxService.svc/AccountBalamceRequest. and then hit enter its unable to find the end point.  I am wondering why ??